# @Html.ActionLink not working in mvc-5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i am creating a web app in mvc-5

here is my actionlink button which looks like

```
<p>
    <span class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "insert")
    </span>
</p>
```

when a user clicks on this button he should be redirected to the following page

```
public ActionResult insert()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

but nothing is happening when i am clicking the button

what i need to do?

Comment: you need to supply parameters properly. At least, controller name, action name, and display text. please check - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: This html with this button is inside a page rendered by the same controller (e.g within index action)?

Comment: @Alisson yes both are on the same controller

Comment: I would also watch out for ActionLink and learn the difference between Url.Action and Html.ActionLink. 99% of the time, you are going to want to use @Url.Action("ControllMethodName","ControllName")

HTML.ActionLink vs Url.Action in ASP.NET Razor

But the most important thing to remember in either case, "ControllerMethodFunctionNAmeHere","AwesomeCoolControllerNameHere"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link format doesn't look correct.

You've only got

```
 @Html.ActionLink(" ", "insert")
```

Add your "Link text", action and controller name and you should be ok.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "YourAction", "YourController")
```

NOTE : There are 9 overloads for ActionLink allowing you to omit the controller (among other things )if the link target is handled by the same controller.

Hope that helps

Comment: OP is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29) which has 2 parameters - the link text and the action name!

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Ah ok.. So he's got a link (No link text) with a span presumably to show a button.... So is his action not in the same controller do you think?  ( Just seen your answer :) )

Comment: OP has confirmed its in the same controller - its just that there is nothing to click :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you not generating any text in the link, there is nothing to 'click'.

Change your code to generate a link containing the `<span>` element

```
<p>
    <a href="@Url.Action("insert")">
        <span class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </a>
</p>
```